# MySql Select Where Column Value Is Unique

Tags: mysql

My table `people_jobs`:

```
+--------+--------+
|  NAME  |  JOB   | 
+--------+--------+
|  John  |  Actor | 
+--------+--------+
|  Jane  | Driver | 
+--------+--------+
|  Bill  |  Actor | 
+--------+--------+
|  John  |  Cook  | 
+--------+--------+
```

I'm looking to select all names with the job actor where the name column would be unique.  The desired query output here would be just *Bill*.

Something like:

```
SELECT name FROM people_jobs WHERE job LIKE "actor" AND COUNT(SELECT * FROM people_jobs WHERE name LIKE name) = 1;
```

This is apparently bad syntax and I couldn't get GROUP BY to work... Thoughts?

Comment: `SELECT distinct name FROM people_jobs WHERE job='actor'` Something like that?

Comment: This still returns both John AND bill.

Comment: That's because john and bill are both actors. You need to rephrase your question. I understand now you want to select all actors with names that are present exactly once in the table.

Comment: You mean who are JUST Actor, without second job, right?

Comment: @CollinD The question is phrased appropriately.

Comment: @webdeb that is correct.  I actually got the answer below already, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why a subselect?

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM people_jobs
WHERE job='Actor'
GROUP BY name
HAVING cnt = 1
```

---

Ok, now I see the problem. Try this instead:

```
SELECT name, SUM(JOB='Actor') AS actor_cnt, COUNT(*) as job_cnt
FROM people_jobs
GROUP BY name
HAVING (actor_cnt = 1) AND (job_cnt = 1)
```

This'll figure out how many people are actors, and count how many jobs they have, and return ONLY the people whose only job is acting.

Comment: I'm still getting both John and Bill back from this query.

Comment: hmm. and now I see the problem. hang on. modified version coming right up.

Comment: Perfect!  I was hoping the answer wasn't THAT easy.

Comment: How would you convert this query to an update statement so that you were updating the name?

Answer (score 3):

```
select name
from people_jobs
where name in (
  select name
  from people_jobs
  group by name
  having count(name) = 1
) and job like 'actor'
```

This example is simple for understanding, but I like another one:

```
SELECT name
FROM people_jobs
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) = 1 AND sum(job = 'Actor') = 1
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation on how this works? Otherwise, good answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) c 
FROM people_jobs 
WHERE job = 'Actor' 
GROUP BY name HAVING c = 1
```

Comment: Should this not be `GROUP BY name`?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo that I just caught. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM people_jobs x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN people_jobs y 
             ON y.name = x.name 
            AND y.job <> x.job 
          WHERE x.job = 'actor' 
            AND y.name IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Strawberry.  I got a useable solution below, but am definitely giving you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I would use NOT EXISTS on this context:

```
SELECT name
FROM   people_jobs
WHERE  job = 'actor'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM people_jobs pj
                       WHERE pj.name = people_jobs.name AND pj.job != 'actor')
```

Answer (score -1):

Easier and solve your problem:

`SELECT distinct name FROM people_jobs WHERE job = "Actor"`